Data exists, but NO data being returned to JS\SmartClient page
I am passing in a comma-separated string from a .aspx page to a vb.net page. I want to cycle through this string and give me the results in a table that is passed back to the .aspx page, displayed in a SmartClient ListGrid. The problem I'm having is that even though the vb.net page shows that the table has been constructed with no errors, no data is being returned. I may be sending the data back to the .aspx page the wrong way or something, because I am getting an empty ListGrid. I am not seeing any errors on the console either... just nothing at all. What am I doing wrong here?
Here is the JS in the .aspx page:
The DataSource-------------
var dataAnimNames = isc.DataSource.create({
dataURL: "DataScripts/ShowAnimalsList.aspx",
recordXPath: "/NewDataSet/DATA",
fields: [
{ name: "AnimalName", type: "text", title: "Name" },
{ name: "Desc", type: "text", title: "Description" }
],
});

The function call----------------
function LoadAnimDesc() {
AnimalsGrid.fetchData(null, "AnimalsGrid.setData(data)", {
params: {
Names: Form1.getValue("sNames")
}
});
};

The ListGrid------------------
var AnimalsGrid = isc.ListGrid.create({
autoFetchData: false,
dataSource: "dataAnimNames",
width: "80%",
});

The Comma separated string being passed to the vb.net page

Mickey,Goofy

//The ShowAnimalsList.aspx vb.net page----------------
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim NameList As String = Request("Names")
Dim Names As String() = NameList.Split(New Char() {","c})
Dim cTypes As New TypeLib.clsTypes
Dim Desc As String

Dim dsNames As New DataSet
Dim dtNames As New DataTable
dtNames.Columns.Add("AnimalName")
dtNames.Columns.Add("Desc")

    
        Try
            If NameList.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Nme As String In Names
                    If Nme.Trim = "" Then Continue For
                    Nme = Nme.Trim
                    Desc = cTypes.GetAnimDesc(clsUtility.ConStr, Nme)
                    Dim row As DataRow = dtNames.NewRow()
                    row("AnimalName") = Nme
                    row("Desc") = Desc
                    dtNames.Rows.Add(row)
                Next
                dsNames.Tables.Add(dtChgs)
                dsNames.Tables(0).WriteXml(Response.OutputStream)
    
            End If
    
        Catch ex As Exception
        'no errors here...
    
        End Try
    End Sub`

This is the table showing in the 'DataTable Visualizer' of the ShowAnimalsList.aspx vb.net page



AnimalName
Desc




Mickey
Mouse


Goofy
Dog




How do you know 'no errors here... when you are swallowing the Exception?

I meant that when I step through the .net code, no errors are being displayed.
